# Extended UserPrincipal returns null

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I am trying to extend UserPrincipal to easily read directory properties. When I debug, the user returns `null`, but I can find the expected information in Current information.

Extended class

```
public class UserPrincipalEx: UserPrincipal
{
  public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext ctx) : base(ctx) { }

  public new static UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext ctx, string un)
  {
    return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, un) as UserPrincipalEx;
  }

  //example of property to retrieve
  [DirectoryProperty("MI")]
  public string MI
  {
    get
    {
      if (ExtensionGet("Initials").Length < 1) return null;
      return ExtensionGet("Initials").ToString();
    }
    set { ExtensionSet("Initials", value); }
  }
}
```

Code that exists elsewhere to retrieve the current user's information.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
UserPrincipalEx user = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, un);
//more code to work with the data
```

Relevant debug info:

[image: Debug info for user variable]

I need `user` to not return `null`.

I have searched through the "similar questions" and tried to follow their examples, but I am unable to get this to work.

**Update 20230105** I tried marc_s's solution below in a new project, no joy.

**Update 20230106** I tried using Convert to change the class of a UserPrincipal, also no joy. Object must implement iConvertible. UserPrincipal does not.

```cs
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, un);
user = (UserPrincipalEx)Convert.ChangeType(up, typeof(UserPrincipalEx));
```

Comment: UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity will always return a UserPrincipal and not a UserPrincipalEx. So casting via as to something it isn't will always be null afterwards.

Comment: I really expected UserPrincipalEx to be a UserPrincipal with more details. I guess that is not how C# sees it...

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before - years ago - and I used to use this code:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx: UserPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext ctx) : base(ctx) 
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx (PrincipalContext context,
                            string samAccountName,
                            string password,
                            bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    { } 

    // Create the "Department" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("department")]
    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("department").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("department")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("department", value); }
    }
    
    // Create the "Manager" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("manager")]
    public string Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("manager").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("manager")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("manager", value); }
    }
}
```

So just basically **do NOT** create a static `FindByIdentity` method, but implement a second constructor. Also, accessing the `ExtensionGet` methods seems to a tad different from your version.

To search for a user, use the `FindByIdentity` defined on the base class - like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
{
    UserPrincipalEx user = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, un);

    // here, "user" should be just fine, 
    // and the "Department" and "Manager" properties should be readable
}
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get the following error,

`UserPrincipalEx user = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, un);`
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal' to 'Models.UserPrincipalEx'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

This is not what I had intended, but it will suffice for this project and may be helpful to someone else in the future.

Taken from [How to implement and call a custom extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method).

```cs
public static class UserEx
{
  public static string MI (this UserPrincipal up)
  {
    return ((DirectoryEntry)up.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties["Initials"][0].ToString();
  }
}
```

```cs
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
{
  UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, un);
  Console.WriteLine($"{up.DisplayName}'s middle initial is {up.MI()}");
  //output: John Q. Public's middle initial is Q.
}
```

Of course, this will only GET data, but another method could be added to SET data fairly easily.